# add_filter (to posts_where) callback function is not calling

Tags: wordpress

I made a file (test.php) in my WordPress root folder, and load it separately from WordPress like this http://localhost/MyWP_Website/test.php
Here are my code:

```
<?php
require_once("wp-config.php");
require_once("wp-includes/wp-db.php");
function myFilter001($where = '') {
    GLOBAL $wpdb;
    $where .= " AND ".$wpdb->posts.".ID > 20 ";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'myFilter001');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => $total,
    'category'          => $category,
    'author'            => $author,
    's'                 => $search,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'orderby'           => 'ID',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

I searched and find that my function is not public but how to make it public? it's with my main code and in my only file that I need?!

Comment: What do you mean 'my function is not public'?

Comment: Why are you attempting to load this code this way? I would suggest using best practices and put arbitrary code in a plugin, instead of the root directory!

Comment: @JimMaguire I mean, my filter function (myFilter001) that I made in my code. Because it's not calling ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

By using WP_Query() instead of get_posts() all filters added to posts_where will working, I just replaced last line of my code.

Replace this:

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

To this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```